# Random access file in PHP

Tags: php, file, random-access

Is there some PHP function or class that allows me to read a file like an array of characters?

For example:

```
$string = str_split('blabla');

$i = 0;

switch($string[$i]){

  case 'x':
    do_something();
    $i++;


  case 'y':
    if(isset($string[++$i]))
      do_something_else();
    else
      break;

   case 'z':
      // recursive call of this code etc..

}
```

I know that I can use `$string = file_get_contents($file)`, but the problem is that I get a huge amount of memory used for a tiny 800K file (like 80MB).

So can I somehow "stream" the file in my code above with some kind of arrayaccess like class that automatically reads data from the file when I call isset()  ? :)

Comment: no its not really random. I will move the $i forward only...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`fseek`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) and [`fgetc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetc.php) to jump around in a file and read single characters at a time.

```
// Leaves the file handle modified
function get_char($file, $char) {
   fseek($file, $char);
   return fgetc($file);
}
```

You mentioned you wanted array behavior specifically. You can build a class which implements [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) to support this.

This could be dangerous for several reasons:

- You'll need to guard against `$char` inputs that request indices past the length of the file
- The file handle will be constantly mutated (should be okay, as long as you're not using it elsewhere)
- This could be inefficient (offset by caching past requests)

---

A slightly more efficient alternative would be to "lazily" read the file (i.e., read it in chunks rather than all at once). Here's some (untested) code:

```
class BufferedReader {
    // The size of a chunk in bytes
    const BUFFER_SIZE = 512;

    protected $file;
    protected $data;

    function __construct($fname) {
        $this->file = fopen($fname, 'r');
    }

    function read_buffer() {
        $this->data .= fread($this->file, self::BUFFER_SIZE);
    }

    function get_char($char) {
        while ( $char >= strlen($this->data) && !feof($this->file) ) {
            $this->read_buffer();
        }

        if ( $char >= strlen($this->data) ) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        return substr($this->data, $char, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's also character encoding to worry about.  You could jump to the point in the middle of a multi-byte glpyh, and that's going to be very upsetting down the line...

Comment: thanks, I managed to do it after all with fgetc (i dont need fseek), memory usage is normal but it seems really slow compared to file_get_contents, like 5 times slower (around 1.5sec). Does this function actually read the file char by char? If so, isn't there a similar function that reads the file like in buffers of 8K? I mean behave like fgetc, but to read the file more efficiently

Comment: @Alex If you want to read in buffers, use [`fread`](http://php.net/fread) and specify the length of data you want to read.  Reading character by character will be slower than reading in buffers and then processing the buffers one at a time until all data has been read.

Comment: +1 for the answer, but PHP already has built-in buffered file reading/streaming, so this is reinventing the wheel.

Comment: how would I use random access with binary?

Answer (score 0):

Use the C+ for random access. C for write (and create if not there), C+ for write and read and create if not there. You can now freely seek, and the file does not get truncated to 0 like when using W.

Questions welcome.
David